# add key to an object from another object

Tags: javascript

I have those two arrays and I'm trying to introduce a new key in the array of objects from the second array with no success

```
 this.dockerApplicationList = [
            {
                lastUpdate: new Date(),
                registryId: 'registryIdOne',
                applicationId: 'appIdOne',
                appName: 'dockerOne',
            },
            {
                lastUpdate: new Date(),
                registryId: 'registryIdTwo',
                applicationId: 'appIdTwo',
                appName: 'dockerTwo',
            },
            {
                lastUpdate: new Date(),
                registryId: 'registryIdThree',
                applicationId: 'appIdThree',
                appName: 'dockerThree',
            },
            {
                lastUpdate: new Date(),
                registryId: 'registryIdFour',
                applicationId: 'appIdFour',
                appName: 'dockerFour',
            },
            {
                lastUpdate: new Date(),
                registryId: 'registryIdFive',
                applicationId: 'appIdFive',
                appName: 'dockerFive',
            },
        ];

  this.spaceList = [
            { name: 'space one', space: '0' },
            { name: 'space two', space: '1' },
            { name: 'space three', space: '2' },
            { name: 'space four', space: '3' },
            { name: 'space five', space: '4' },
        ];
```

I need to  introduce the name of spaceList in as a new key in dockerApplicationList

This is what I'm trying this but it's not working:

```
for (let i=0; i<this.dockerApplicationList.length; i++) {
    for(let x=0; x<this.spaceList.length; x++) {
        this.dockerAppplicationList[i]['space'] = this.spaceList[x].name;
    }
}
```

Why is this not working?

Comment: on which matching criteria you want to add new key?
Like on some condition ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try using map with spread syntax:

```js
let dockerApplicationList = [
    {
        lastUpdate: new Date(),
        registryId: 'registryIdOne',
        applicationId: 'appIdOne',
        appName: 'dockerOne',
    },
    {
        lastUpdate: new Date(),
        registryId: 'registryIdTwo',
        applicationId: 'appIdTwo',
        appName: 'dockerTwo',
    }
];

let spaceList = [
    {name: 'space one', space: '0'},
    {name: 'space two', space: '1'},
];

dockerApplicationList = dockerApplicationList.map((e, index) => (
    {...e, ...{'name': spaceList[index].name}}
));
console.log(dockerApplicationList);
```

---

Or just key assignment:

```js
let dockerApplicationList = [
    {
        lastUpdate: new Date(),
        registryId: 'registryIdOne',
        applicationId: 'appIdOne',
        appName: 'dockerOne',
    },
    {
        lastUpdate: new Date(),
        registryId: 'registryIdTwo',
        applicationId: 'appIdTwo',
        appName: 'dockerTwo',
    }
];

let spaceList = [
    {name: 'space one', space: '0'},
    {name: 'space two', space: '1'},
];

dockerApplicationList = dockerApplicationList.map((e, index) => {
    e['name'] = spaceList[index].name;
    return e;
});
console.log(dockerApplicationList);
```